# TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not builtin_function_or_method

Tags: flask, jwt, flask-restful, passlib

I am trying to implement **JWT** authorization to a Flask app. However when I try to login, It returns a `"500 Internal server error"` with a "TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not builtin_function_or_method". What could I be missing out here.

***Here is my class from models.py***

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

# Create classes to store data.
class User:
""" This class provides a way to store user data. """

    users = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'username': u'mwinel',
            'email': u'mwinel@example.com',
            'password': u'code618'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'username': u'lucy',
            'email': u'lucy@example.com',
            'password': u'123456'
        }
    ]

    def __init__(self, id, username, email, password):
        """ Initialize objects. """
        self.id = user_id,
        self.username = username,
        self.email = email,
        self.password = password

    @staticmethod
    # Generate a hashed string to be
    # stored by our class model.
    def generate_hash(password):
        hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(password, rounds = 20000, salt_size = 16)
        return hash

    @staticmethod
    # Check a given password.
    def verify_hash(password, hash):
        return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, hash)
```

***And here is my login method***

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from app.models import User

class UserLogin(Resource):
    # Call the method to login a user.
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('username', required = True)
        parser.add_argument('password', required = True)

        data = parser.parse_args()
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        for user in User.users:
            if password == User.verify_hash(data['password'], hash):
                return {
                    'message': 'Logged in as {}'.format(data['username']),
                }, 200
        return {
            'message': 'Something went wrong'
        }, 500
```

***And here is the error***

```
TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not builtin_function_or_method
```

Answer (score 0):

When this line is reached you haven’t defined a hash at all:

```
if password == User.verify_hash(data['password'], hash):
```

I believe this would normally raise a NameError, however there is a built in python function called hash that is trying to be passed into your verify_hash method instead (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#hash). This is what is causing your program to blow up with that exception.

Comment: How would I define the hash in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
if password == User.verify_hash(data['password'], hash):
```

for

```
if password == User.verify_hash(data['password'], user['hash']):
```

but you are not storing those hashes which makes all your encryption useless.

Instead use your hashing function to store your password hashes in your users array like so:

```
# Create classes to store data.
class User:
""" This class provides a way to store user data. """

    users = [
        {
            'id': 1,
            'username': u'mwinel',
            'email': u'mwinel@example.com',
            'hash': u'$pbkdf2-sha256$20000$OCeEcM55zzlnbG3tfW9tTQ$k3dRDawLaOMlR4cehJEP/2b0JUTMrtPedzLYxNQWICM'
        },
        {
            'id': 2,
            'username': u'lucy',
            'email': u'lucy@example.com',
            'password': u'$pbkdf2-sha256$20000$8D6H0Npbaw3BWGsNYSxFyA$FxkRkBXuQy8VFRX8dSdygzQ4vNlvFJl6hWZQ6LT2NIc'
        }
    ]
```